# How to convert a specific element of a String into an int Arduino/C++

Tags: c++, string, arduino, type-conversion, integer

I was working on a converter project using Arduino/C. At a certain point in my code, a `String` sequence of 0's and 1's is generated, as an example:
`my_string = "01101";`. I want to process this data in a for loop like shown in this minimal example:

```c
String x = "01011", y = "00011"; // These variables necessarily must have the same length

for(int i = 5; i > -1; i--) // Going from last index to first
{
    bitsum = x[i].toInt() + y[i].toInt(); // Summing up each pair of bit, here is the problem
}
```

My point is: is there a way to take an exact and specific element of the `String` and convert it to `int` one by one?

 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arduino is usually programmed in C++, and that you use the `String` class means you're doing it as well.

Comment: He was simply deducing that you were not talking about C because your code uses the Arduino (i.e. C++) `String` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the characters of `my_string` will *always* be numerals, then the typical method of obtaining a `char` numeral's numeric value is by just subtracting `'0'`.  This works because the ASCII values for the numerals are arranged in order, so by subtracting `'0'`, you're subtracting their offset (48) from the actual 0 value.

The [`charAt(n)`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/charat/) method can be used to get the character at a given index.

```
bitsum = x.charAt(i) - '0' + y.charAt(i) - '0';
```